# Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document error while serializing from java

Tags: xml, serialization

when i serialize a graph from java to xml by storing a firstnode, remaining nodes and edges in a xml file it gets stored. but when i open the xml file it gives me an error "Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document Error processing resource 'file:///D:/DM1/tro.xml'. Line 17, Pos...

```
</GraphPanel_-Node><GraphPanel_-Node>
--------------------^
```

here is the code

```
 private class Serialize extends AbstractAction {
    XStream xs = new XStream();


        public Serialize(String name) {
            super(name);

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {




            ListIterator<Node> iter = nodes.listIterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Node n = iter.next();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("D:/DM1/tro.xml",true);
                    if(!n.fnode){
                        xs.toXML(n, fs);
                        }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                iter.remove();
            }

            ListIterator<Edge> Eiter = edges.listIterator();
            while (Eiter.hasNext()) {
                Edge edg = Eiter.next();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("D:/DM1/tro.xml",true);
                    xs.toXML(edg, fs);


                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                Eiter.remove();
            }

            ListIterator<Node> Fiter = nodes.listIterator();
            while (Fiter.hasNext()) {
                Node n = Fiter.next();

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("D:/DM1/tro.xml",true);
                    if(n.fnode){
                        FirstNode f =new FirstNode("Root");
                    xs.toXML(f, fs);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                Fiter.remove();
            }

}
}
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ that's what the XML looks like? The start and end tags are in the wrong order.

Comment: no, this is not the whole xml file. if i open in text file i see the xml with node and edge classes. But in any xml parser it would give me an error.

Comment: Whatever is serializing the XML is doing it wrong.  It appears to be outputting multiple top-level `<GraphPanel_-Node>` elements without an enclosing root node. That is invalid XML so you need to fix the application that is writing the output to enclose everything in, for example, `<Nodes>... your XML output...</nodes>`

Comment: bool DBWrapper::executeDMLStmt (string sql)
{
    strcpy(dSql,sql.c_str());
    EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :dSql;
    if(sqlca.sqlcode!=0)
 {    return false;}
    EXEC SQL COMMIT;
    return true;
} 

bool DBWrapper::openConnection()
{
  EXEC SQL CONNECT :uname IDENTIFIED BY :password;
  if (sqlca.sqlcode!=0)
  {return false;}
  return true;
}

Comment: bool DBWrapper::fetchHandsetList(vector<Handset>& handsetList)
{
 EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
        int handsetId;
        char modelName[25];
 float price;
        EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
 EXEC SQL DECLARE handsetCur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM Handset5;
 EXEC SQL OPEN handsetCur;
 //cout<<"OPEN CURSOR"<<sqlca.sqlcode;
 for(;;)
 {
  EXEC SQL FETCH handsetCur INTO :handsetId,:modelName,:price;
  if(sqlca.sqlcode!=0)
   {
    break;
   }
  Handset h(handsetId,modelName,price);
  handsetList.push_back(h);
 }
 EXEC SQL CLOSE handsetCur;
 return true;
}